# Using Django w/ mod_wsgi and Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I've been trying to work out how I'll go about setting up a Django application on production, when it's ready for deployment. I'm using Django v1.11, and my EC2 is running Ubuntu 14.04. I have been attempting to refer to [this guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) as reference, however it is not specific to Ubuntu, so I've been experiencing a bit of difficulty in this regard. I've referred to several other resources, but much of what is out there seems to be outdated.

I have a host rule set up on my local machine, pointing `www.example.com` to my EC2 instance's public IP address.

I have a virtualenv set up which lives in `/home/django/example.com/ENV`. My Django project lives in `/home/django/example.com` directly. The project name is `mysite`, and was generated using `django-admin startproject mysite`, thus it has the default `wsgi.py` file inside the `/home/django/example.com/mysite` directory. The contents of `wsgi.py` look like:

```
"""
WSGI config for mysite project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I've tried adding VirtualHost rules such as the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django/example.com/mysite/wsgi.py

    <Directory "/home/django/example.com/mysite">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Similarly, I've tried adding:

```
Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

to `/etc/apache/apache2.conf` and chucking the following:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django/example.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /home/django/example.com/ENV
WSGIPythonPath /home/django/example.com

<Directory /home/django/example.com/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

into `httpd.conf`.

In either case, I've restarted the Apache server directly afterwards.

I'm not getting any further than hitting "500 Internal Server Error" or hitting an "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

Anyone able to shed some light around a) where I'm going wrong, b) where I can refer to for up-to-date instructions, or c) how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: If you are getting no error messages in the Apache error log, a 500 error indicates it likely is getting to the Django application but is failing in Django. Django by default doesn't log details or errors to the error log, you need to set that up. Until you setup logging properly, set ``DEBUG=True`` temporarily in Django settings module and see if the details of the error are then displayed back in the browser.

Comment: You should also use daemon mode of embedded mode of mod_wsgi. Using embedded mode is not recommended. For how to set up Python virtual environment when using daemon mode see http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of troubleshooting, and consulting with the resource mentioned in Graham's comment, here's what I established was required in my VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        Alias /static /home/django/example.com/static

        <Directory /home/django/example.com/static>
           Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/home/django/example.com:/home/django/ENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages

        WSGIProcessGroup mysite
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django/example.com/mysite/wsgi.py

        <Directory /home/django/example.com/mysite>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and here are the contents of `wsgi.py` that I settled on:

```
"""
WSGI config for mysite project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os, sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

path = '/home/django/example.com'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

And it is also worth noting (simply because it wasn't immediately obvious to me) that it is necessary to specify:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/example.com/static'
```

in `settings.py`, and to run `python manage.py collectstatic` to collect static files from all applications into said `STATIC_ROOT`.

I hope this helps somebody else, in future!

Comment: Do not use ``python-path`` to set up the Python virtual environment. Use ``python-home`` for that part as explained in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html That is, you don't what ``site-packages`` mentioned in ``python-path`` anywhere. That way of specifying location of Python virtual environment is not recommended.

Comment: You also don't need to add ``/home/django/example.com`` to ``sys.path`` in the WSGI script file. That directory being mentioned in ``python-path`` option is enough.

Comment: Hmm... Changing `WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/home/django/example.com:/home/django/ENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages` to `WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/home/django/example.com python-home=/home/django/ENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages` doesn't seem to work. I get a bunch of `Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding` errors in my Apache log, and eventually `Script timed out before returning headers: wsgi.py`. Removing the `sys.path` stuff from `wsgi.py` was a safe move, though! Any ideas?

Comment: Further, in case you're wondering why I stuck the `site-packages` in my `python-path` initially, I was referring to this resource: http://django-project-skeleton.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apache2_vhost.html

Comment: There is a lot of documentation out there which uses the very very very old way of doing things and doesn't use the preferred method that has existed for 5+ years.

Comment: It is supposed to be ``python-home=/home/django/ENV``. That is, it is meant to refer to the root of the virtual environment. This is explained in then doc I mentioned about using the virtual environment.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Thanks for your help - we got there in the end!